# Spring @Value Could not resolve placeholder in string value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

Have the context spring conf like this, I have 2 property-placeholder in my context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.app.xxx"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:em-management.properties"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="file:///opt/ass/swp/conf/platform.properties"/>

</beans>
```

When I run the code, met this error:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CMClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.xxxx.app.xxxx.xx.client.CMClient.washost; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerHost' in string value "${com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerHost}"

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.xxxx.app.xxx.xxx.client.CMClient.washost; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerHost' in string value "${com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerHost}"

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerHost' in string value "${com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerHost}"
```

how to solve this issue？

Comment: Do you have defined the string `com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerHost` in one of your property files?

Comment: Don't use multiple `<context:property-placeholder />`  elements, use a single one. `location` takes a `,` separated value, so use `location="classpath:em-management.properties,file:///opt/ass/swp/conf/platform.properties"` instead of 2 elements.

Comment: @Jens, yes, it's existing.

Comment: @Deinum, I will try your approach.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this particular problem,just append `ignore-unresolvable="true"` to **each line**.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:em-management.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///opt/ass/swp/conf/platform.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

Comment: That isn't really a solution, the actual solution is to not use multiple placeholder `<context:property-placeholder />` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use multiple `<context:property-placeholder/>` tags, refer below code for the same and also make sure you have a key `"com.ibm.CORBA.securityServerHost"` with a value in either of your property file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">
      <list>
         <value>classpath:em-management.properties</value>
         <value>file:///opt/ass/swp/conf/platform.properties</value>
      </list>
   </property>
   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```